# Swift2では例外処理とかの記述が変わったらしいのですが、[fm removeItemAtURL:newURL error:nil];　はどう書けばいいですか？

Tags: swift

Swift2では例外処理とかの記述が変わったらしいのですが、
Objective-Cの次のコードの、Swift2での書き方がわかりません。
どう書けばいいですか？

```
NSFileManager *fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
[fm removeItemAtURL:newURL error:nil];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let fm = NSFileManager()
do {
    try fm.removeItemAtPath(path)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

このような感じですね。バリエーションとして、エラーを単に無視する `try? fm.removeItemAtPath(path)` や、エラーがあった時にクラッシュする、 `try! fm.removeItemAtPath(path)`　という書き方があります。 `try?` あるいは `try!` を使うと `do~catch` ブロックは不要になります。

[Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-CのError Handlingについてのドキュメント](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID10)にほぼ同じ内容が載っています。

参考:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID10

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html

Answer (score 2):

Objective-CからSwift2において、例外の記述方法が変更されましたが、末尾が`NSError**`の引数が、機械的に`throws`句に変換されるという対応になっています。

```
NSFileManager *fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
[fm removeItemAtURL:newURL error:nil];
```

このコードを単に直訳した場合、

```
let fm = NSFileManager()
try? fm.removeItemAtURL(newUrl)
```

になります。もともとエラー内容を取得する`error:`の引数に、`nil`を渡しているためです。

---

エラーハンドリングの方法は以下の三通りあります。

- **`do～catch`構文と`try`を利用して検査例外として扱う**
  エラー内容を`catch`句で取得して、具体的な処理を行う必要がある場合
- **`try!`を利用して実行時例外として扱う**
  エラーの発生はプログラムの異常動作であり、アプリが強制終了するべきである場合
- **`try?`を利用して例外が発生した場合には何もしない**
  エラーの内容は軽微であり無視しても良い場合（エラーの具体的な内容を知る術がない点には注意）